# PowerShell script to stop service and backup a folder in remote path

Tags: windows, powershell, copy, backup

How to

1. Stop a service
2. Backup a folder/contents in a remote path as per sys date
3. Remove the contents of the original folder
4. Finally to start the service

```bsh
Get-Service SERVICENAME
Stop-Service SERVICENAME -Force –PassThru
Start-Sleep -s 20

Copy-Item -Path \\remote path\folderderA -Destination \\Remoate path\folderA(Get-Date) -Recurse -Verbose
Remove-Item -Path \\remote path\folderA -Verbose

Start-Sleep -s 20
Start-Service SERVICENAME -Force –PassThru
Get-Service SERVICENAME
```

The above code is throwing an error.

Comment: Without knowing the error it's difficult to tell what's causing it. Errors in PowerShell are usually written in quite understandable way, so please cite it in your question.

Comment: Hmm... I spy with my little eye a) en-dashes that should be hyphens, b) spaces in unquoted paths, and c) a `Get-Date` without explicit format that will likely produce invalid path characters. Please [edit] your question and provide a more accurate version of the code you're running as well as the full error message.

Comment: Did you stop service as administrator? Maybe you don't have the rights to do it? 
Maybe the location is not available? 
Without error, we can only guess, please edit and put this error. 
Have you try run only 1/3 of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, pretty sure the issues you might have had were around the (Get-Date) in the middle of a string and possibly the fact directories can't contain special chars like / or : which are in the date.

Also as other people have said, do this as an administrator.

```
Get-Service SERVICENAME | Stop-Service -Force
Start-Sleep -seconds 20

$Date = (Get-Date).ToString().Replace("/","-")
$Date = $Date.Replace(":","-")

Copy-Item "\\remote path\folderderA" -Destination "\\Remoate path\folderA-$Date" -Recurse -Verbose
if(Test-Path("\\Remoate path\folderA-$Date")){Remove-Item -Path \\remote path\folderA -Verbose}
Start-Sleep -seconds 20

Start-Service SERVICENAME
Get-Service SERVICENAME
```

Comment: Hi Darkcell ,
The scripts worked .But am looking to add all these to a log file as an update and mail to me . Any trick to enable these ...

Comment: To add logging try using try catch blocks.with the out-file cmdlet e.g.

    Try
    { 
        stop-service $servicename -force
        success | out-file c:\file.log -append
    }
    catch
    {
        $error[0] 
    }